# AddOrUpdate() method not found using VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, iqueryable

I am trying to convert a ***C# code into VB code*** :

In the C# codes it can call AddOrUpdate method, but when I code it in VB it's not found in the intellisense.

**c# code:**

```
  protected override void Seed(eManager.Web.Infrastructure.DepartmentDB context){
         context.Departments.AddOrUpdate( d => d.Name,
                  new Department() { Name = "Engineering"},
                  new Department() { Name = "Sales"}
         );
     }
```

**VB Code:**

But when I code in VB the method AddOrUpdate(), I can't find it. The declaration of DepartmentDB class is like this:

```
 Imports System
    Imports System.Collections
    Imports System.Collections.Generic
    Imports System.Linq
    Imports System.Text
    Imports System.Threading.Tasks
    Imports System.Data.Entity
    Imports eManager.Domain

    Public Class DepartmentDB
       Inherits DbContext
       Implements IDepartmentDataSource

    Private _DBEmployees As DbSet(Of Employee)
    Private _DBDepartments As DbSet(Of Department)

    Public ReadOnly Property Departments As IQueryable(Of Department) Implements IDepartmentDataSource.Departments
        Get
            Return _DBDepartments
        End Get
    End Property


    Public ReadOnly Property Employees As IQueryable(Of Employee) Implements IDepartmentDataSource.Employees
        Get
            Return _DBEmployees
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: It seems to me another part of your library, or solution, isn't building and this is just a symptom of that.

Comment: @DominicKexel, you're on to something there, the `Import` probably isn't there; what namespace is it in?

Answer (score 7):

I think you are missing

```
Imports System.Data.Entity.Migrations
```

since AddOrUpdate() is an extension method: 
[MSDN article for AddOrUpdate method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.idbsetextensions.addorupdate%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)